# How do I inflate Protobuf extensions?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

```
message base
{
    required int32 cmd = 1;
    extensions 1000 to max;  
} 

message derived
{
    extend   base{ required derived test = 1001; }
    required int32 a = 1;

    extensions 1000 to 3000;  
}

message derived2
{
    extend   derived{ required derived2 b = 1001; 
    required int32 b = 1;
}
```

considering that this is the proto file.

How would i inflate derived.a and base.cmd while creating a derived2 protobuf object in C#?

considering the solution would be involving either protobuf / protobuf-net library

Comment: Which protocol buffer library are you using?

Comment: @Jon Skeet : protobuf-net library

Comment: Right, I've added the relevant tag. Unfortunately I don't know enough about protobuf-net to help you :(

Comment: +1 for silencing Jon Skeet. Many have tried...Few succeed. Fewer live to tell the t.....  x|

Comment: @Jon Skeet, How do we achieve the same in google protobuf ?

Comment: @user3301278: I'd have to look, to be honest - it's been a while since I've worked with extensions in my own port. But you'd call `GetExtension` on the `Base` instance, basically. See https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/source/browse/src/ProtocolBuffers.Test/ExtendableMessageTest.cs for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protobuf-net currently does not have huge support for `extend` / `extensions`. What it *does* to is let you access unknown members of such types, as long as the type had somewhere to put that information when deserializing. If you started from protogen this should already be the case - otherwise, the simplest option is to change your POCO to inherit `Extensible`. With that done, `Extensible.GetValue<T>` offers a basic mechanism to access undeclared members via their field number.